# Python postgres cursor.execute очень медленный

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Postgresql, сервер достаточно слабый - 512 мб оперативки, интернет канал 10 мб. Количество строк в таблице - 2.5 млн

Колонки таблицы:

```
        CREATE TABLE public.well_completions
    (
      year smallint,
      name character varying(255),
      operator_num integer,
      facility_num character varying(255),
      facility_name character varying(255),
      well_name character varying(255),
      api_county_code character varying(255),
      api_seq_num character varying(255),
      sidetrack_num character varying(255),
      api_num character varying(255),
      formation_code character varying(255),
      formation character varying(255),
      county character varying(255),
      field_name character varying(255),
      field_code integer,
      qtrqtr character varying(255),
      sec character varying(255),
      twp character varying(255),
      range character varying(255),
      meridian character varying(255),
      dist_e_w integer,
      dir_e_w character varying(255),
      dist_n_s integer,
      dir_n_s character varying(255),
      lat numeric,
      "long" numeric,
      ground_elev numeric,
      utm_x integer,
      utm_y integer,
      spud_date timestamp without time zone,
      td_date timestamp without time zone,
      wbmeasdepth integer,
      wbtvd integer,
      gas_type character varying(255),
      test_date timestamp without time zone,
      well_bore_status character varying(255),
      status_date timestamp without time zone,
      first_prod_date timestamp without time zone,
      form_status_date timestamp without time zone,
      formation_status character varying(255),
      complete_date timestamp without time zone
)
```

Создал индекс:

```
CREATE INDEX yearindex
  ON public.well_completions
  USING btree
  (year);
```

Простейший запрос

```
SELECT * FROM well_completions WHERE year='2000';
```

В pgadmin3 выполняется за минуту. Посредством питона:

```
 cursor.execute(query)
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
```

Вообще не дожидаюсь выполнения
Пробовал:

```
cursor.execute(query)
        for row in cursor:
```

Еще дольше. Ставлю брейкпоинт, так он в минуту где то по 10 тысяч записей всего извлекает.
Судя по EXPLAIN - запрос использует индекс.
Пробовал изменять work_mem и buffered - скорость та же

Comment: Я точно не знаю использует ли PostgreSQL индексы при неявной конверсии типов, но лучше на всякий случай изменить `year='2000'`на `year=2000`. Сколько записей в таблице для `year=2000`, т..е. что показывает `SELECT count(*) FROM well_completions WHERE year=2000;`?

Comment: Запустите запрос и проверьте нагруженность хоста, где работает PostgreSQL сервер. Также посмотрите его логи на предмет ошибок и предупреждений о том, что не хватает места и / или памяти.

Comment: Судя по плану запроса, он не должен быть тяжеловесным

Comment: База используется монопольно или еще кем-то? Возможно, что-то загружает базу/сервер?

Comment: Какой драйвер доступа к PostgreSQL используется: psycopg2 или pg8000? Может, дело в настройках драйвера для python...

Comment: Используется ли SSL при соединении с PostgreSQL?

Comment: Моежт поможет что-то отсюда, если еще не пробовали: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198380/improving-postgres-psycopg2-query-performance-for-python-to-the-same-level-of-ja

Comment: Записей в таблице по year='2000' где-то 160 тысяч. SSL используется. Но пробовал тестить и без него - когда включаю /time и через путти тестирую запрос в psql, то скорость не изменяется и с локалхоста на выборку уходит где-то 1.5 секунд. Драйвер - psycopg2. База на данный момент используется только мною, сервер vps на digitalocean.

Comment: Как то странно вообще всё это. Через pgadmin запрос извлекается за 1 минуту, что в общем то нормально, я полагаю, при таком слабом сервере, но почему тот же запрос через psycopg2 извлекается в 20 раз медленнее?

Comment: Тот же самый sql запрос на языке C# у меня занял 11 секунд...